# Missing number treated as zero in overleaf

Tags: errors, thesis

I'm currently working on my thesis and when I compile the acknowledgements alone it has no error but once I compile everything it shows this error.
[image]

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article} 

% -------------- Setup, do not change these ---------------
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc, url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{minted} % Code highlighting
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} % Mathematical packages
\usepackage{parskip} % Removing indenting in new paragraphs
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % needed for correct table numbering
\counterwithin{table}{section} % numbering of tables 
\counterwithin{figure}{section} % numbering of figures
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % numbering of equations
\hyphenpenalty=100000 % preventing splitting of words
\sloppy 
\raggedbottom 
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Fotnotes are fixed to bottom of page
\usepackage{lipsum} % For genereating dummy text
% --------- You can edit from this point on --------


% ----- Appearance and language ----- 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % document language
\graphicspath{{Images/}{../Images/}} % path to images
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % sets margins for the document
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5} % line spread for the document
\usepackage{microtype}


% ----- Sections -----
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries} % \section heading
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries} % \subsection heading
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries} % \subsubsection heading
% next three lines creates the \paragraph command with correct heading 
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


% ----- Figures and tables ----- 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % bold text for captions
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable} % fancy tables, check these before you use them
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}


% ----- Sources -----
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa} % citation and reference list style
\def\biblio{\clearpage\bibliographystyle{apa}\bibliography{References.bib}} % defines the \biblio command used for referencing in subfiles - DO NOT CHANGE


% ----- Header and footer -----
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} % page number on right for odd pages and left for even pages in the header
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % chapter name and number on the right for even pages and left for odd pages in the header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % sets thickness of header line
\fancyfoot{} % removes page number on bottom of page


% ----- Header of the frontpage ----- 
\fancypagestyle{frontpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \vspace*{1\baselineskip}


    \fancyhead[L]{ \includegraphics[width=6.8in]{ensao.jpg}} % change to nhhlogo1.png for golden NHH logo
}


% ----- Document starts here ----- 
\begin{document}

\def\biblio{} % resets the biblio command, if not here a new reference list will be produced after every chapter

\include{NHH-Frontpage}
\restoregeometry % restores the margins after frontpage
%\nocite{*} % uncomment if you want all sources to be printed in the reference list, including the ones which are not cited in the text 

\pagenumbering{gobble} % suppress page numbering
\thispagestyle{plain} % suppress header
\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage % add blank page

\begin{quote}
     ``\textit{\textbf{Imagination is more important than knowledge. Knowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the world}}.''
\\[5pt]
\rightline{{\rm ---  Albert Einstein}}
\end{quote}{

\pagenumbering{roman} % starting roman page numbering
\newpage
\section*{Acknowledgements}
    \subfile{Chapters/Acknowledgements}

\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
    \subfile{Chapters/Abstract}

\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} % line spacing for the list
\tableofcontents
}

\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} 
\listoffigures}

\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} 
\listoftables}

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}} % sets depth of toc to 4, 1.1.1.1
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Starting arabic page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1} % sets pagecounter to 1

\section{Introduction} % section/chapter name
    \subfile{Chapters/01Introduction} % including the subfile for the chapter
\clearpage % clears the page after the chapter is finished

\section{Background}
    \subfile{Chapters/02Background}
\clearpage

\section{Data}
    \subfile{Chapters/03Data}
\clearpage

\section{Methodology}
    \subfile{Chapters/04Methodology}
\clearpage

\section{Analysis}
    \subfile{Chapters/05Analysis}
\clearpage

\section{Discussion}
    \subfile{Chapters/06Discussion}
\clearpage

\section{Conclusion}
    \subfile{Chapters/07Conclusion}
\clearpage

\newpage
\renewcommand\refname{References} % name for the reference list
{\setstretch{1.0} % linespacing for the references
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} % to change the name of the references in the TOC
\bibliography{References.bib} % adds the references to the document
}

\newpage
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix} % Heading of appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix} % name of appendix in TOC
\appendixpage 
\addappheadtotoc

\begin{appendices}
    \subfile{Chapters/Appendix}
\end{appendices}

% TIPS AND TRICKS - REMOVE WHEN YOU DON'T NEED IT ANYMORE
\newpage
\section{Tips and tricks to get you started}
    \subfile{Chapters/Tips}

\end{document}
```

Here is the acknowld code :

```
\documentclass[../Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

\lipsum[ \$I warmly thaactor.
I express my deep gra my sincere thanks.I would like to thank Mr.. ]
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\center National School Of Applied Sciences\

\center Oujda, June 2019
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}

\makebox[2.5in]{Waf} \qquad \qquad \qquad  \makebox[2.5in]{JURY}



\end{document}
    enter code here
```

Comment: You are using `\lipsum` with an optional argument, which should be a number. I don't see what `\lipsum` -- which sets dummy text -- is doing here at all. Just remove it completely.

Comment: Is your issue solved with the comment above? No? Did you solved it? How?